# Where can I find the org source code for orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html

Tags: org-mode

The title pretty much says it all: I'm looking for the "org source"<sup>1</sup> for the page http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html.  (I want to replicate several aspects of that page's formatting.)

---

Many org-mode documentation pages (e.g. [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/index.html)) have a <kbd>Show Org Source</kbd> button, but the page I'm interested in is not one of them.

---

EDIT: To see what I mean by "org source", please click the <kbd>Show Org Source</kbd> in [the page I cited](http://orgmode.org/worg/index.html).  Alternatively, you can see it [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/index.org.html).

What I'm **not** after is the HTML source that one can view by, for example, pointing one's browser to view-source:http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Assuming, of course, that the web page in question was generated from an org document.  This assumption could be incorrect; if so, please let me know.</sup>

Comment: You are probably looking for this: http://orgmode.org/manual/JavaScript-support.html#JavaScript-support

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was not familiar with the concept of "org source" - which, from what I understand now, is the Org document that the html was generated from (if it was generated from one). When I click `Show Org Source` it just takes be to the top of the same rendered page, so that increased my confusion.

Comment: @elethan: Try this page: http://orgmode.org/worg/index.org.html.  (Apparently there's a bug with the [Show Org Source] button I originally referred to.  More specifically, it fails in http://orgmode.org/worg, but it works in http://orgmode.org/worg/index.html.)  I've edited my post to fix this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download org source, you'll see the manual is provided as a texinfo file (as well as info and pdf, both generated from texinfo).

However, some have tried to rewrite it in org.  See [this post from 2013](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-02/msg01517.html) and [this thread from 2015](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/98836).  They both link to a stale github [repo](https://github.com/tsdye/orgmanual) that was last updated three years ago but since you only need it as an example it may be usefull for you.